# Problems with if ....==NULL in C

Tags: c, null, fopen

I have this code, note that it is shortened down. The problem is if the file exists
it still overwrites it. Been 30 years since I did any programming so bear with me. Thanks!

```
FILE *openFil(FILE *open, char namn[]);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    FILE *openFil(FILE *open, char namn[]);
    FILE *anmal =NULL;

    char filNamn[] = "ANMAL.DAT";
    postTypAnm pAnm;
    anmal = openFil(anmal, filNamn);
}

FILE *openFil(FILE *pointer, char name[])
{
    if ((pointer =fopen(name, "r+b"))== NULL)
        if ((pointer =fopen(name, "w+b"))== NULL)
        {
            /* It Enters here as well, but it should not do that or????? */
            printf("error\n");  
            exit(0);
        }
    return pointer;
}
```

Comment: Try `perror(name);` inside the `if` body. Maybe your runtime library can help?

Comment: Try providing the full path and filename. Maybe the default path opens in a write-protected location.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the C11 standard you can use the "x" argument to specify that if the file exists the `fopen()` function will fail.

For reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/

Comment: Not an answer, maybe rewrite as a comment?

Comment: hmmm... the description of the `"x"` in [C11 7.21.5.3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.3) is *somewhat* different to the description on the link you posted.

Comment: Differs in what way? It states there as well that you would need to add the "x" specifier to the mode argument.

Comment: The description in the link you posted does not mention *exclusive access*.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't mention that. Regarding the exclusive access the OP should have a look at the concepts of the OS that the program is written for. To see if the concepts of exclusive access are actually implemented. The link you posted is a better choise it seems.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1.

> "*It Enters here as well, but it should not do that or?????*"

No, It shouldn´t. If both pointers are `NULL` the opening of the streams to `ANMAL.DAT` were not successful, neither in `w+b` nor in `r+b` mode. Proof if the file really exist in the directory of the executable. Else try to use the entire path from the root directory to the file.

> "*The problem is if the file exists it still overwrites it.*"

Why do you know that the file is really overwritten in a proper manner?

Since `if ((pointer =fopen(name, "r+b")) == NULL)` and `if ((pointer = fopen(name, "w+b"))== NULL)` both fail, it seems that the `ANMAL.DAT` does not exist where `fopen()` searches for it or otherwise an error occurs when trying to open it (maybe has incorrect format or is corrupted?).

Place `perror(name)` in the error routine to check if `errno` was set to indicate an error at `name`.

---

#### 2.

In the error routine: `exit(0)` is not correct if an error has happened. Use `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`.

---

Side note:

You have another prototype for the function `openFil`-> `FILE *openFil(FILE *open, char namn[]);` inside of `main`, which is redundant.

Also the identifier of the second parameter is different in the prototype before `main` to the identifier at the definition of `openFil`, `namn` in comparison to `name`.

Comment: @KeithThompson Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool openFile(FILE **ptr,
    const char *fileName);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    FILE *anmal = NULL;
    const char *fileName = "ANMAL.DAT";

    if(!openFile(&anmal, fileName)) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

bool openFile(FILE **ptr,
    const char *fileName)
{
    *ptr = fopen(fileName, "w+bx");
    if(!*ptr) {
        perror("Error opening file: ");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

This is using the `x` extension in GNU C to test whether the file exists.

As other people have pointed out, there are numerous problems in your original code.

- You've redeclared the function prototype for `openFil` within `main`.
- In `openFil` there's no point in both accepting the `FILE` pointer as
  a parameter *and* overwriting it with the return value. Especially if
  you're expecting to input a `NULL` pointer and use the function to
  initialise it. Either use a pointer-to-pointer as a parameter so you
  can modify the pointer within the function, or ignore it completely
  and set its value with the function's return value. Not both.
- You're not actually testing for whether the file exists at all. According to the manual pages for fopen (`man fopen`) neither of the flags you used in opening the file (`r+` and `w+`) care whether the file exists. `r+` opens for reading/writing and always positions the stream at the beginning of the file. `w+` opens for reading/writing, truncating the file if it exists already. This explains why you didn't get the effect you intended.